# Counting number of times each IP address appears in log file

Tags: awk, sort

I have a file in the format as follows:

```
$ cat file.txt

27.33.65.2
27.33.65.2
58.161.137.7
121.50.198.5
184.173.187.1
184.173.187.1
184.173.187.1
```

What's the best way to parse the file `file.txt` into a format like:

```
27.33.65.2: 2
58.161.137.7: 1
121.50.198.5: 1
184.173.187.1: 3
```

In other words, I want to loop through the file and count the number of times each IP address appears. I've already run it through `sort` so all the IP addresses are in order and directly after each other.

Comment: I, personally, would import this sort of file into a handy nearby DB (by creating a temp table in any postgres instance I've got around), followed by a quick SQL action and export back to a text file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're looking for [`uniq -c`](http://man.cx/uniq)

If the output of that is not to your liking, it can be parsed and reformatted readily.

For example:

```
$ uniq -c logfile.txt | awk '{print $2": "$1}'
27.33.65.2: 2
58.161.137.7: 1
121.50.198.5: 1
184.173.187.1: 3
```

Comment: Combining `uniq` and `awk` does not seem to be a great approach to me...

Comment: Doesn't seem to work here, doesn't catch and count duplicates properly.

Comment: Because `uniq` only works on sorted input (it matches adjacent matching lines, not any lines from the file).

Comment: @HaukeLaging - what exactly is wrong with the uniq/awk approach? I'd be curious to hear specific reasons.

Comment: You must sort the results prior to piping them to uniq. If you read the original Q the OP states that he's already sorted the results using `sort`!

Comment: @slm The reason is not specific but very general: Do not use two programs if one of them can do the job alone (unless there are good reasons to use two nonetheless). Why let `uniq` do the counting if `awk` gets invoked anyway? Save a process, save task switches (for bigger amounts of data). Let alone that no sorting is necessary for the `awk` solution.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - I appreciate what you're saying but in the same way that most users of computers will never venture beyond OSX & Windows, further still most users of Unix will not venture beyond using designated tools for specific tasks. Using AWK is not for the faint of heart, look at what you had to do to perform this basic task using AWK vs. what Glenn's solution required. I think I'm being fair in saying that his is a simpler solution to mentally grasp, though yours is likely more efficient. BTW, I did UV both since they're both correct!

Comment: @HaukeLaging - your perspective on things is what drove my comment about you not actively A'ing Q's BTW. We have a few key individuals that have very specific skills which the broader audience here will likely gain very valuable knowledge by these persons continued participation in providing A'ers 8-). These persons should liken themselves to being teachers more then solving any one particular person's Q. You, Gilles, Stephane, Glenn, and others...

Comment: @slm It's probably the best approach to show both possibilities (in cases like this), even if you are the only one who answers. Then everyone in the audience can decide whether (and when) he prefers the easy to understand or the efficient solution.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - Yes, exactly. As you hang around the site our responsibilities change slightly, IMO. We're responsible for making comprehensive A'ers and looking at the A'ers we provide as teaching moments to the OP and every future visitor that comes across it, again IMO. But it's a personal choice so if you have only a few minutes to spare then providing an A in any form is always appreciated.

Comment: This post was helpful, but I found I had to do a little preprocessing in order to get it to work like I wanted.  This will count the IP addresses in the Apache access log requesting xmlrpc: `cat access.log | grep xmlrpc | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2": "$1}'`

Answer (score 6):

`uniq` seems to be the cleverer solution, indeed. The awk way:

```
awk '{ip_count[$0]++}; '\
'END {for (ip in ip_count) printf "%15s: %d\n",ip,ip_count[ip];}' file
```

Comment: +1. If the order of the output is important to the OP, this answer does not make any guarantees: iterating over the keys of an associative array has not inherent order.

Comment: @glennjackman But adding `sort` to my answer is still faster as fewer items have to be sorted. ;-)

Comment: oh yeah? OH YEAH?!? ;) the input is already sorted. This awk answer shuffles them, so it's still more work. Nyah! ;)

Comment: Looking back at that comment, I'm embarrassed. Even with the smilies, it's pretty damn obnoxious. My apologies.

Comment: @glennjackman Seriously, after so many years? I honestly don't remember but I doubt I felt that way back then. The remark was appropriate. The `awk` solution could be both faster and keep the order. But you need a lot of data to make it worth the additional coding effort... And I didn't pay attention to the input already being sorted. I hope it stays more important what we say than how we say it.

Comment: heh heh, as a Canadian, it is my patriotic duty to say "sorry" as often as possible.

Answer (score 0):

firest sort file then get count by unic -c

`sort filename | uniq -c`

Comment: The file is already sorted (according to the user in the question), and `uniq -c` would work but provide the output on the wrong format.  This is why [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118337/116858) does not use `sort` and instead reformats the output of `uniq -c`.

Comment: Thanks @Aeyd. I was looking for this command. It helps

Answer (score 0):

I would use python. Every linux ststem nowadays has python2 installed.

Add each ip address into a dict (associative array) as key=value pairs i.e. {"12.34.56.78":1, "87.76.43.21":3}.

You 'verify' the ip address as a key and increment the value by 1. If you use defaultdict("ip"), if the key doesn't exist, it is created with a default value of 0.  If the key does exist already, defaultdict does nothing. The value is incremented on the next line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

infile = open("file.txt","r")
iplist = {}  # create an empty dict

for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()   # remove newline.
    if line: # if not a blank line.
        iplist.setdefault(line, 0) # check for ip and add with default value of 0
        iplist[line] += 1 # increment

outfile = open("out.txt","w") #open output file

for key in iplist.keys():
    line = "%-15s = %s" % (key, iplist[key])
    print line   # print uf desired.
    outfile.write(line + "\n")
```

outout file:

```
cat out.txt                                                          
27.33.65.2      = 2
58.161.137.7    = 1
121.50.198.5    = 1
184.173.187.1   = 3
```

I know you were looking for a command line solution, but as you can see it is an elegantly formatted display that only took a dozen lines or so. Python is an excellent tool for administration.